# How to check if a nested list is a subset of another nested list

Tags: python, list, comparison

I have 2 lists as `list<list<list>>` lists where I want to check if one of them is a subset of the other.

```
list_1 = [
           [
             [1,2],[2,3]
           ],
           [
             [3,4],[5,6]
           ]
         ]
list_2 = [
           [
             [3,4], [5, 6]
           ]
         ]
```

So expected output is that as list2 has [[[3,4]]] which is a part of list_1 so it should be a subset.

list_1 has 2 elements and its second element matches the first element in list_2 so list_2 is a subset of list_1.

The comparison is not at the element level but at list level.

I tried `set(list_2) < set(list_1)` but results in `unhashable type: list`. How can I achieve the above comparison then?

Comment: Is there some reason these are wrapped in a redundant list? Also, is the order relevant?

Comment: Now in your example `list_2` is not a subset of `list_1` but `list_2[0]` is a subset of `list_1[0]`. Is that intended?

Comment: @a_guest So list_1 has 2 elements and its second element matches the first element in list_2 so list_2 is a subset of list_1.

Comment: @Atihska Okay then, after this update to your example, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55270652/3767239) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over `list_2` and check whether its elements are contained in `list_1`:

```
list_1 = [[[1, 2], [2, 3]], [[3, 4], [5, 6]]]
list_2 = [[[3, 4], [5, 6]]]

all(x in list_1 for x in list_2)  # Option 1.
all(map(list_1.__contains__, list_2))  # Option 2.
```

The second version works for lists (and other types) but `a in b` is more general since it falls back on `b.__iter__` if `b.__contains__` is not defined.

Comment: It was an auto correct I believe that did not had list<list<list>> but something else. Please check my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Sets can't hold lists because sets rely on their elements being immutable and lists are mutable. If you switch the lists to tuples it'll work:

```
list_1 = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]
list_2 = [(2,3), (3,4)]
```

```
set(list_2) < set(list_1)
```

You could also change the outer lists to tuples, but I left them as lists to make it clear which ones ought to be tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested lists so a simple comparison won't work. Here is a function that checks if l2 is a subset of l1 :

```
list_1 = [[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]]
list_2 = [[[2,3],[3,4]]]

def comparison_nested_lists(l1,l2):
    l1,l2 = l1[0],l2[0]
    l2_in_l1 = True
    for i in l2:
        if i not in l1:
            l2_in_l1 = False
    return l2_in_l1

print comparison_nested_lists(list_1,list_2)
```